# Android Studio shows blank documentation for Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Firebase for my Android Studio project. Whenever I press **ctrl+Q** to show documentation for any **Firebase** functions or classes, **it shows a blank box**. This doesn't happen for functions from other libraries.

[Blank documentation box screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHOGR.png)

How to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

> OS Linux Kubuntu 18.04 &  Android Studio 3.5

Comment: Go to Android studio config->options folder present in your user HOME and then find the jdk.table.xml file and replace this line <root type="simple" url="http://developer.android.com/reference/" /> to your android sdk downloaded docs->reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the correct documentation for Firebase. That's all that is displayed in Android Studio by default.

> **The documentation is provided in the downloaded library itself.** For example, when
>   you do ctrl+click on a function of a library whose text documentation
>   is visible to you, you'll be taken to it's definition in the
>   downloaded library and there you'll see it's
>   text documentation just above the function.

Comment: Is there a way to display the real documentation?

Comment: No, because the documentation is provided in the library itself. For example, when you do ctrl+click on a function of a library whose text documentation is visible to you, you'll be taken to it's definition in the downloaded library and there you'll see just above the function, it's text documentation.